# SAS macros to print multiple reports

Tags: macros, sas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
data have;
    input name $ class $ time score;
cards;
chewbacca wookie  1 97
chewbacca wookie 2 100
chewbacca wookie 3 95
saruman wizard 1 79
saruman wizard 2 85
saruman wizard 3 40
gandalf wizard 1 22
gandalf wizard 2 50
gandalf wizard 3 87
bieber canadian 1 50
bieber canadian 2 45
bieber canadian 3 10
;
run;
```

I'm creating a program that does two things:
1. prints the data for each distinct class
2. creates a scatterplot x=time y=score for each name.

Executing the code below will illustrate my desired output:

```
data chewbacca saruman gandalf bieber;
    set have;
    if name='chewbacca' then output chewbacca;
    else if name='saruman' then output saruman;
    else if name='gandalf' then output gandalf;
    else if name='bieber' then output bieber;
run;

title 'Report for wookie';
proc print data=have;
    where class='wookie';
run;
title 'Plot Chewbacca';
proc sgplot data=chewbacca;
    scatter x=time y=score;
run;
title 'Report for wizard';
proc print data=have;
    where class='wizard';
run;
title 'Plot Saruman';
proc sgplot data=saruman;
    scatter x=time y=score;
run;
title 'Plot Gandalf';
proc sgplot data=gandalf;
    scatter x=time y=score;
run;
title 'Report for canadian';
proc print data=have;
    where class='canadian';
run;
title 'Plot Bieber';
proc sgplot data=bieber;
    scatter x=time y=score;
run;
```

Ideally, I'd like to automate this.  I've been trying to set this up, but am missing something.  Here is my attempt:

```
proc sql;
    select count(distinct name) into :numname
    from have;
    %let numname=&numname;
    select distinct name into :name1 - :name&numname
    from have;
    select count(distinct class) into :numclass
    from have;  
    %let numclass=&numclass;
    select distinct class into :class1 - :class&numclass
    from have;
quit;

%macro printit;
%do i = 1 %to &numclass;
title 'Report for &&class&i';
proc print data=have;
    where class=&&class&i;
run;
/*insert sgplot here*/
%end;
%mend;
%printit;
```

Please help here.  Can't get the syntax sorted....

Thanks.

Comment: can you give us the error you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 4 issues.

1. Macros will only resolve inside double quotes.  Single quotes mask the resolution. So change the title statement to:

   `title "Report for &&class&i";`
2. The class variable is a string.  You need to quote the string in the where clause:

   `where class="&&class&i";`
3. You don't need to generate the separate data sets. You can add a where clause when you specify the data for `SGPLOT`

   `proc sgplot data=have(where=(name="&&name&i"));`
4. The number of names and classes are different, so you need two loops.

EDIT: Also look at `SGPANEL` and/or `SGRENDER`.  You can generate all the charts in 1 call.

Comment: Thanks @DomPazz.  This is definitely what I was looking for.  I'll look into the other procs you suggested as well, to see if those are better for this program.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` procedure and most ODS procedures support by-group processing, which might be a lot simpler and save a lot of time depending on what you require.

```
proc sort data=have; by class;
proc print data=have;
    by class;
run;
```

and

```
proc sort data=have; by name;
proc sgplot data=have;
 by name;
 scatter x=time y=score;
run;
```